# No PHP, o ponteiro interno de um array compõe seu valor?

Tags: php, array, característica-linguagem

Consideremos o seguinte *array*:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Ao fazermos `$b = $a` criamos uma cópia do *array*, tanto que alterações feitas em um dos *arrays* não afetará o outro.

Porém, percebi que a posição do ponteiro interno do *array* também é copiado. Se antes de definirmos `$b` como sendo uma cópia de `$a` nós mudarmos a posição do ponteiro:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

next($a);  // Move o ponteiro interno uma posição a frente

$b = $a;
```

Ao verificar o valor atual de `$b`, teremos o valor 2, pois o ponteiro está na segunda posição:

```
echo current($b);  // 2
```

Ao movermos o ponteiro de `$a` antes da cópia, o *array* `$b` será gerado já com a posição nova do ponteiro; mas se a posição do ponteiro for alterada depois da cópia, a alteração não afeta `$b`.

Portanto, a posição do ponteiro interno de um *array* compõe seu valor, copiado junto quando o objeto é copiado? Isso seria esperado? A minha impressão foi que ao copiar um *array* eu copiaria apenas os valores, reiniciando a posição do ponteiro.

Comment: Sim, existe um valor intereno no array que diz qual é o elemento que ele ta apontando, ou seja quando copiar o array ele deve copiar sim o valor do ponteiro atual. Veja mais informação [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28059424/9643815) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30454445/9643815).

Comment: @fajuchem já respondeu a pergunta!

Comment: @IvanFerrer Ele comentou uma possível resposta, mas ainda não respondeu.

Comment: @fajuchem seria interessante formalizar como resposta, pegando a parte relevante dos links

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de visualizar qual é o funcionamento interno do tipo array é se basear na interface [Iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), uma implementação bem simples pra este modelo seria:

```php
<?php

class MyArray implements \Iterator
{
    /**
     * Valores úteis da array
     *
     * @var mixed[]
     */
    private $data = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');

    /**
     * Representa o ponteiro interno
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $key = 0;

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->data[$this->key];
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->key;
    }

    public function next()
    {
        $this->key++;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->key = 0;
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return isset($this->data[$this->key]);
    }
}
```

Veja que o ponteiro interno é parte integrante do objeto, porém não é possível acessá-lo diretamento por se tratar de um atributo *private*.

Seguindo esta idéia, sempre que você faz uma cópia de um objeto baseado nesta classe, o ponteiro interno também será copiado sem sofrer nenhuma alteração e o compartamento que você descreveu na pergunta é de fato aquilo que se espera.

Caso seja realmente necessário que o ponteiro seja zerado ao copiar o objeto, você poderá implementar uma classe semelhante a esta que demonstrei e acrescentar a ela o método mágico `__clone()`:

```php
class MyArray implements Iterator
{
    // ...
    public function __clone()
    {
        $this->rewind();
    }
}
```

Sempre que for fazer uma cópia do objeto, será necessário utilizar a instrução `clone`:

```php
<?php

$a = new MyArray();
$a->next();

$b = clone $a;

echo sprintf("a: %s\nb: %s", $a->current(), $b->current());
```

e o resultado:

```
a: bar
b: foo
```

Comment: É uma abordagem interessante. Saberia dizer como funciona com o `array` nativo, que não implementa `Iterator`? Cheguei a analisar a implementação em C do PHP e encontrei a `struct` que representa o array internamente constando o ponteiro para a posição atual, só não encontrei onde ele copia esse ponteiro quando eu reatribuo o *array* para outra variável.

Comment: Infelizmente eu não sou bom o bastante de C pra te indicar onde a mágica acontece. Porém eu acredito que funcione exatamente da mesma forma que o Iterator, o que muda é o paradigma *POO* para *funcional*.

Answer (score -1):

A reposta é **sim**. Mas não tem a ver com o valor em si, o fato é que a posição da chave é que contém o valor. O ponteiro apenas diz qual é a chave atual, e se nesta chave contiver o valor atual, então, sim está compondo seu valor. Sempre que for utilizar array, parte da premissa de que a posição ou chave é quem possui valor, e não outra coisa, o array é basicamente uma coleção de chaves que possuem valores.

**Associação de variável é uma cópia exata de sua origem... por isso é evidente que sim.**

Mesmo que haja uma última interação, que muda seu comportamento de origem, internamente é uma nova estrutura, neste sentido você estará copiando esta nova estrutura, com sua novas condições e regras, ele foi mutado, e agora isso também faz parte do escopo do array.

Todo array tem um ponteiro interno para o elemento "atual", o qual é inicializado para apontar para o primeiro elemento inserido em um array.

A função **current()** simplesmente retorna o elemento do array para o qual esse ponteiro interno está apontando. Não move o ponteiro de forma alguma. Se o ponteiro interno estiver apontando para além do final da lista de elementos ou o array é vazio, **current()** retorna FALSE.

> **end()** - Faz o ponteiro interno de um array apontar para o seu último elemento
>   **key()** - Retorna uma chave de um array
>   **each()** - Retorna o par chave/valor corrente de um array e avança o seu cursor
>   **prev()** - Retrocede o ponteiro interno de um array
>   **reset()** - Faz o ponteiro interno de um array apontar para o seu primeiro elemento
>   **next()** - Avança o ponteiro interno de um array

Ao definir um array comum com valores, sem chaves: `$array = ('valor 1', 'valor 2', 'valor 3')`, por padrão, quando não definimos as chaves, ele é  interpretado, por número 0, 1, 2... desta forma, internamente é a mesma coisa, ele possui um ordem pré-estabelecida de inclusão das chaves/valores:

```
$array = array(
0 => 'valor 1',  /* internamente : -> current é 'valor 1', 
                    que é chave 0 (pois é o primeiro valor a 
                    ser inserido no array  */
1 => 'valor 2', 
2 => 'valor 3'
);
```

Ao usar o método: `next($array)`, por exemplo, você está modificando internamente, a posição do atual (current) valor inserido no array, para o próximo, mas a chave e o valor continuam no mesmo lugar, se ordená-lo, vai notar que a ordem das chaves **não** mudou nada visualmente:

```
sort($array);
print_r($array);
```

**Saída:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => valor 1
    [1] => valor 2
    [2] => valor 3
)
```

`$array[1]` que possui a chave 1, e valor `'valor 2'`. Ou seja, utilizando o método `current($array)`, você estará obtendo a chave e o valor, da nova posição "interna".

Comment: Não sei se entendi a resposta, mas parece haver uma confusão entre o valor do objeto em si com o valor armazenado no *array*. Você consegue detalhar melhor como funciona o processo de cópia deste ponteiro interno ao fazer a atribuição?

Comment: Não existe valor do objeto, porque array não é um objeto... array e objetos são coisas distintas. Vamos lá, o que vc tem no array é apenas um índice de peso, que é definido internamente no método do array, e isso só pode ser modificado através dos métodos que eu coloquei na resposta.

Comment: Array é um objeto na memória. Estou falando em baixo nível, de ponteiros, não em alto nível. A pergunta trata de porque/como o valor deste ponteiro é copiado junto com o objeto array (esquece objeto do PHP e pense em objeto da computação em si). A maior parte da resposta fala sobre como manipular o valor deste ponteiro interno, mas não é esse o foco da pergunta.

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida afinal? Eu já respondi, mesmo em baixo nível, esse valor binário é mudado internamente. Somente através destes métodos. chaves e valores não mudam de lugar. Através destes métodos.

Comment: A resposta esperada é uma demonstração do porque o ponteiro que indica qual é a posição atual compõe o valor do objeto do array que é copiado durante a atribuição.

Comment: Mas isso está na minha resposta: (...Todo array tem um ponteiro interno para o elemento "atual", o qual é inicializado para apontar para o primeiro elemento inserido em um array.). Este é o motivo.

Comment: Sim, mas essa informação já era conhecida. A pergunta é sobre o comportamento deste ponteiro durante a cópia do objeto. Apenas isso, não sobre como manipulá-lo.

Comment: Também está na resposta, o comportamento... Ao usar o método: next($array), por exemplo, você está modificando internamente, a posição do atual (current) valor inserido no array, para o próximo, mas a chave e o valor continuam no mesmo lugar:

Comment: Sabe a batata quente... ela fica na mão de quem você quiser... isso não muda o fato de vc ser quem é.

Comment: Então, isso trata de como essas funções lidam com o ponteiro, não como o PHP opera durante a cópia. A pergunta é bem mais simples do que você está querendo responder. A resposta seria "Sim, porque durante a cópia do objeto o PHP irá fazer... copiando também o ponteiro". Não é necessário falar como o desenvolvedor pode alterar a posição.

Comment: Vejo que a discussão está se desvirtuando, então me ausentarei. Continuo achando que a resposta não respondeu minha pergunta. Se acha que sim, pode mantê-la sem problemas. Sempre é mais conteúdo para a comunidade. Obrigado pela tentativa.

Comment: O que o @AndersonCarlosWoss quer saber é se o ponteiro interno de estão a falar compõe o "objecto" do array, ou seja, se ele é ou não copiado quando o array é copiado. E se devia ser assim ou não!? Tipo o array é compostos pelos seus elementos + um ponteiro interno?